# How to submit all sessionStorage content to PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-storage

I am currently working with something like the below but I'm having trouble with syntax in assigning all of my sessionStorage data to a variable and passing that through to my PHP:

```
var exampleValueOne = "Value A";
var exampleValueTwo = 2;
var exampleValueThree = "Value XYZ";

//Example value from my HTML modal where multiple of the same 'users' may be captured
var dropDownValue = $('#aDropDown').find('option:selected').attr('value');

//Some assignments
sessionStorage.setItem("valueA", exampleValueOne );
sessionStorage.setItem("valueB", exampleValueTwo );
sessionStorage.setItem("valueC", exampleValueThree );

//Need to be able to assign an indeterminate amount of valueD key value pairs
if (sessionStorage.getItem("valueD1") === null) {   

    var countNumber = 1;           
    sessionStorage.setItem("valueE", countNumber);

    for (var i = 0; i < countNumber; i++){  

    sessionStorage.setItem("valueD"+[countNumber], dropDownValue);

    }

} else {

    //if at least one valueD exists it means we need to add after the last one  
    var countNumber = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("valueE"));  
    //update the count
    sessionStorage.setItem("valueE", (countNumber + 1));

    for (var i = countNumber; i < (countNumber + 1); i++){

        sessionStorage.setItem("valueD"+[countNumber], dropDownValue);

    }

}
```

> sessionStorage should look as follows after the above:
>
> valueA: "Value A"
>
> valueB: "2"
>
> valueC: "Value XYZ"
>
> Assuming two values have been saved using for loop they would be save as
>   such (value 8 and 2 are just random example attribute values from the html side):
>
> valueD1: "8"
>
> valueD2: "2"

```
//NOW I would like to pass these values to my PHP using Ajax

var data = {
            /*ALL SESSION STORAGE ITEMS?*/
            };                                                             

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "myPHP.php",
                data: data,
                success: function(){                    
                return false;
                }
                });
```

Comment: Looks nice. Good luck. Let us know if you have a question along the way.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks, but not sure how to pass all of my sessionStorage content through from a syntax point of view? How do I place sessionStorage into var data?

Comment: Add you actual question to your post...  not as a comment. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Apologies @MagnusEriksson I was so obsessed with formatting my code in a clean logical way with the stackoverflow site, that I forgot to ask my question clearly!

Comment: The question is kinda defined in the title haha, just put "How to" in the front of the title ;)

Comment: @SanderVisser - Now when it's changed, yes. Not when I wrote the comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `length` property and `key(i)` method to get all the keys that are used in the sessionStorage. with those keys you can retrieve the values just like normal

```
sessionStorage.setItem("valueA", '1' );
sessionStorage.setItem("valueB", '2' );
sessionStorage.setItem("valueC", '3' );

//Create data object so we can submit it to the server 
var data = {};
for(var len = sessionStorage.length, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var key =  sessionStorage.key(i);
    data[key] = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
}
console.log(data);

//From this point you can post the `data` to your server side
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "myPHP.php", data: data });
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply @SanderVisser I'm testing this now, but makes complete sense, will mark as correct answer etc. shortly.